# VHDL testbench real-life example

Tags: testing, vhdl, verification, testbed

I think I've read most of the textbooks that dedicate chapters, sections, or the entire text to writing testbenches in VHDL. Still, I have the impression that none of them shows the real thing. Seriously, if that's all there is to writing testbenches, then the whole verification process looks a little flaky to me.

Is there any real-life, high-quality, industry-level testbench VHDL code that is open for study?

PS: I just finished reading *Writing Testbenches - Function Verification of HDL Models*, and though it's a great book, I'd still like to see some real-life code examples based on the methodology proposed in the book.

Comment: Take a look at www.osvvm.org for some newer testbench verification techniques. An interesting counterpoint to Bergeron's book.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, I'm a big fan of OSVVM, I've run the examples there (FIFO & Sensors) and they are great as a tutorial, but the sample projects are small. Do you know of anything bigger that is available as open source?

Comment: No, and I agree something of the sort would be a useful project ... maybe verifying a LEON system using OSVVM with ghdl... all open source! The upcoming ghdl 0.32 release supports enough VHDL-2008 to run OSVVM-2014.01. If you come across a good example project, add a comment or answer here...

Comment: At my work, our best VHDL testbenches are system level, and are primarily used to weed out the obvious problems; even they aren't comprehensive. The brunt of the functional verification testing is done on the actual hardware by a whole division of testers emulating customer use cases. (Note: we use FPGAs, I imagine it would be different for ASIC production)